# Shared session between two different PCs

Tags: php, caching, session, cookies

I am developing a shopping cart for a client and I got a very strange feedback from my client. I use CakePHP and as in common practice a shopping cart is identified by a PHP session. As far as I know even on the same machine if we open two different browsers then PHP will create two different sessions as the server session is tied to the browser's cookies.

My client said that when she tested the online store on two different PCs in her office (so obviously in the same network) all items that she has added to the shopping cart on the first computer would appear on the shopping cart on the other computer. I am wondering if that is possible at all due to specific configuration on her office's intranet? Even if it is due to the browser cache, it will not be shared between two computers?

Any thought or input? Thank you.

Comment: @user152235: Did she test your application or just refer to experience with another application?

Comment: Is the shopping cart stored in the session or the database?

Comment: She did some tests on my application.

Comment: Shopping cart is stored in the database which is identified by a session ID

Comment: Then it is not possible. I think that she missed something.

Comment: That's what I thought ... thank you for confirming that ... I am a bit confused how that happened.

Comment: Are you sure it happened or not? Did the client give you screenshots of the two PCs to show you the problem, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt two PCs will share the same session/cookies. If that ever happened, we'll have session hijacking commonplace across the Internet. The only thing I can think of that would lead her to believe the session is shared is when you have a buggy application that's sending the same (read: **wrong**) data to different users.

Comment: Hi stillstanding, I am sure that's not the case ... not only that I can't see anything that might cause that in my code ... but also for the fact that the cart will be empty once she pressed F5 (refresh) on the second computer. The only possibility is that the same product has been added to the cart before on that PC ... but it is all too coincidental ...